# Rails migrations for multiple databases and postgresql relations awareness

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-7

Assuming all databases of a rails 7.0.3 application are on the same server (be they replicas or not)

- Where primary database (`app_development`) has a table `shop`
- a secondary database (`appusers_development`) has a table `role`
- there is a third database (`applocal_development`) that will need to
  connect as well.

If a migration is created in the secondary database, where

```
t.references :shop, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: true
t.references :role, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: true
```

this migration will not pass, as postgresql has no knowledge of the connection to the other database: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "shops" does not exist`

Different users exist for main database `deploy_root` and replicas `deploy_readonly`.

It does not appear that this is set out in rails functionalities, thus how can it be accomplished with postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to have a foreign key constraint (or any constraint) between databases (not in postgresql, and not in any engine AFAIK).  The whole idea of a relational database is that the relations are contained within a (single) database.  Anything outside of that (arguably other than something like a read replica) needs to be handled outside of that.